# htaccess - multiple extension hiding

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove `.html` and `.php` extensions in my `.htaccess` file. I want the users to be able to view *www.example.com/page.php* by clicking either *www.example.com/page.php* or *www.example.com/page*, but the browser always to show *www.example.com/page*

Tried a few options I found online, and this one was working for me:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Which I thought was great, I could browse between pages like I mentioned above.

However, it then failed trying to log in to any of my pages. When I entered the credentials, it would just re-open the page I was on, with no error message.

The `.php` pages have a `require("connection.php");` in the file to get the access to the database.

Then goes something like:

```
<?php
    require("connection.php"); 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // check credentials
        // redirect to specific page
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    // the rest of the form
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out the php rewrites in the `.htaccess` the login works as expected. It's not a database issue, as I can view pages that display data from there with no issues.

Is there something in my `.htaccess` file that's improperly redirecting my `.php` pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#Without redirection with POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/[^.]+)\.(html|php) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: Hmm ignoring post requests; that might work, I’ll be able to check in a few hours. . +1 for combining the extensions together :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried routing all the requests through one file?

Usually what you want to do is reroute ALL traffic for php or html files to a main index.php file and have that load up the proper file requested.

That way you have one pipe line that will handle all the special cases, preparation of the files, etc..

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Very simplified index.php

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
function render($file, $vars = []) 
{
    if(file_exists($file) {
        ob_start();
        extract($vars);
        include($file);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}

function route($file) 
{
    $absolute = __DIR__ . $path;
    $extensions = ['.htm','.html','.php'];
    if(file_exists($absolute)) {
       return render($absolute);
    }
    else {
       foreach($extensions as $ext) {
           if(file_exists($absolute . $ext)) {
              return render($absolute .$ext);
           }
       }
    }
    return false;
}
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
if($output = route($path)) {
   echo $output;
}
else {
   echo render(__DIR__.'/errors/404.html');
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't edit `index.php`; it's just the homepage with a login form that enters `if(!empty($_POST))` if the form on that page was submitted. But I guess what you're suggesting is put all traffic to `bla.php` and then re-direct from there? Will this work (hiding extensions obviously) with the `php` form submission?

Comment: This is how all popular frameworks route their traffic in one way or another but in essence boils down to this. That way they only have to load all the supporting libaries once, then have their routing code decide where to push the request to(require a file, provide ajax response, providing forbidden access/show login form, etc...) You can then put all the files also in a templating directory away from the main web root, preventing direct access. just replace hte __DIR__ with the path to the "template/includes" root.

Comment: For example, I have my own website, that runs from F:\www\sitename\index.php that loads F:\cms\route.php that loads templates from F:\default-template\index.html . When a path is just '/' or ends with '/' just add 'index' before passing it into the route function or modify route to add the index filename.